# LoadLibraryW call hangs on IIS

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net-mvc, iis, pinvoke

I am building an MVC 5 web app that makes some P/Invoke calls to an unmanaged library (loaded via LoadLibraryW function).

It all works well inside visual studio with IIS Express, but once I publish it and run it with the local instance of IIS, the call to LoadLibraryW function hangs indefinitely.

To make sure the problem isn't with my unmanaged library, I created a new "dummy" one with just a simple message box on DllMain function, but it also hangs...

I have tried a lot of things, from enabling 32 bits on the AppPool, to changing the AppPool user, etc.

The AppPool runs in integrated mode, and it is running on a Windows 10 machine.

Is there any sort of configuration or special permissions for p/invoke calls inside IIS that I am missing?

This is how I am P/Invoking the LoadLibraryW function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW(string fileName);

var moduleHandle = LoadLibraryW(@"c:\dll\interop.dll"); // This call hangs forever
```

Has this to do with CAS? The AppPool .NET Trust Levels are set to Full (internal) and I even changed the AppPool identity to LocalSystem so I don't understand.

Anyone experienced this behaviour?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: I can see the file and the VC++ runtime libraries are getting loaded via Process Monitor and I see no errors there, that's why this behaviour is odd.[image]

Comment: Message box? It definitely doesn't work in IIS with non interactive user. There are permissions to call unmanaged code too.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti Why does it show on IISExpress though? I mean, you can place the code you want inside the DllMain...it hangs...

Comment: Because it runs as logged in user. IIS will run with its own non interactive users (think: does it make any sense for a server to display something because of an action started by a client? What if there are 5000 clients? What if no one is even logged in at server?).

Comment: **Without message boxes** you should check if you have permissions to run in full trust. Some service providers still use medium trust by default even if full is now mandatory for ASP.NET

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I am running in a local box, as Local System and Full Trust. The Message Box comment makes sense :) Let me try it without it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti. Without the Message Box works, nice catch! :) Still have to figure out on why the "real" dll  is having the same hanging behaviour as I have no message boxes there ;) I am voting up your comment. Please provide a formal answer so that I can accept it ok? Anyways do you thing that on my "real" dll the problem may be related with any code that probably requires a logged user?

Comment: It's too poor to be an answer and it actually doesn't answer your original question. It may be, but it's hard to say. you may check with your original dll in IIS Express using Process Explorer, you'll see if it opens some handle to UI or what (causes may be multiple, access permissions for example)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes I will do it as you say and if I discover the reason I will post it here so that a more complete answer can be given. Thanks!

Comment: You are starting a message box from DllMain? OK... Read Raymond Chen about what you are allowed to do under the loader lock. Answer: Nearly nothing.

Comment: That was just "dummy" code to try to investigate the problem. In fact you can run a message box from DllMain, the problem was like @AdrianoRepetti very well noticed, running that code in a non iterative session. Anyways I already solved the problem with the "real" library and it had to do with file system writing permissions, but I wasn't getting any error messages that could lead me into any direction to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem had to the fact that I had code in the "real" unmanaged library that was persisting a file into the **%Temp%** folder without having write permissions to do it.

Because that operation did not raised any sort of exception and just failed silently it took me a while to understand that the subsequent code that was wating on that operation to succeed was in a sort of "deadlock" state, so the reason for the "hanging" behavior.

Now, it worked under IISExpress because as @AdrianoRepetti stated, IISExpress runs in a iterative session mode so the **%Temp%** folder was directly associated with the logged in user (under the **\Users{MyUser}\Local\Temp**) , thus having write permissions for that user.

When ran under IIS that **%Temp%** folder becomes the **\Windows\Temp** folder and in there you need to give IIS_USRS group permissions to write into it.

When trying to figure out what the problem was I created a "dummy" unmanaged library that instead of leading me into the right direction it made me think that the problem was related with the P/Invoke action itself as this "dummy" library was also hanging when p/invoked (but it was because of the message box code I had in DllMain just to warn me that the library was loaded).